# C# RabbitMQ - How to know when all messages have been acknowledged

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I have a .net core 2 WebAPI which writes files path to a RabbitMQ queue and then opens a process that consumes those messages and doing some background processing on those files that may take some time to complete.

I have this code snippet which tells me that the queue is empty, but since each message can take time to complete it is a false positive and I cannot use it for this purpose:

```
public bool HasMessages(string queueName)
{
    return channel.QueueDeclare(
                        queue: queueName,
                        durable: false,
                        exclusive: false,
                        autoDelete: false
                    ).MessageCount > 0;
}
```

Is there a way to know when all messages of that queue have been acknowledged before I continue in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If RabbitMQ management plugins are enabled and you have safe route then you can utilize RabbitMQ HTTP API which will give you all the meta information about your RabbitMQ server.

Now for getting unacknowledged messages, you can query the following URL which will return JSON as a response which contains unacknowledged messages count.

`http://username:password@rabbitmq_server_name:15672/api/queues/vhost_name/queue_name/`

In the response of the above URL, there will be a property `messages_unacknowledged` which return unacknowledge message count.

If you don't want to call this URL through HttpClient in C# then you can use [EasyNetQ](http://easynetq.com/) which provide very useful functionality to interact with RabbitMQ HTTP API.

Comment: What is `rabbitmq_server_name`? Is it `localhost`? And `vhost_name`? is it also `localhost`?

Comment: I tried as follows: `http://localhost:15672/api/queues/vhost_name/FilesQueue/` and got this: `{ error: "Object Not Found", reason: "Not Found" }`

Comment: `vhost_name` is a virtual host which you can see on the upper right corner of the portal. I think your `vhost` is `/` so try this: `http://localhost:15672/api/queues/%2f/FilesQueue/`

Comment: Your answer is missing the user and password: `http://USER:PWD@localhost:15672/api/queues/%2f/FilesQueue`. If you'll edit your answer I could mark it as solved.

Comment: @LiranFriedman Added username and password to make HTTP API URL complete.